# Is it possible to contruct a simple graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to construct a Simple Graph with $7$ Vertices with $20$ edge, $21$ edge, $22$ edges?

Based on the information provided. I can conclude that simple graph can have at most of the $n-1$ edges mapped to one vertex.

Therefore $7\times(7-1)$ i.e. $7\times6$ i.e $42$ MAX total edges. Hence $\frac{42}{2} = 21$ Max edges is possible.

So It is possible to construct a simple graph with $20$ and $21$ edges.

Is the argument correct?

Comment: Since $K_7$ has $21$ edges you can rule out $22.$

Comment: Thanks. Is E(Kn ) = n(n-1)/2 ? @coffeemath

Comment: Smit-- Yes, by your argument. But you shoud include that the 42 count has counted each edge twice, hence need to divide by 2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's correct. The maximum number of edges occurs in the *complete* graph $K_n$ which has $n$ vertices each connected to the other $n - 1$ vertices for a total of $n(n - 1)/2$ edges. You can also view this as taking an edge between every pair of vertices, of which there are $n$ choose $2$. So this gives a combinatorial proof that

$$ {n \choose 2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Is E(Kn ) = n(n-1)/2 ?

Comment: @Smit I've only seen people using $E(G)$ for the set of edges in $G$, not the number of edges. If you are asking if the complete graph has $n(n-1)/2$ edges then the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks. If they ask you to check if we can construct a tred with same vertices and edges, how do i check?

Comment: @Smit Draw a few trees. There is a simple relationship between the number of vertices and the number of edges; find it and try to prove it (using induction).